# Excel Required for Connection Manager?

Tags: ssis

Does Excel have to be installed on the machine in order to use the Excel connector in SSIS 2012.  Since it appears it only needs a driver, I'm wondering if we can simply install a driver as opposed to the entire Excel software package on this machine.  Anyone run into this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install Excel on the server to use the connector.  I have used the connector on a production server and we did not need to install any extra binaries or bits.